# Use asx files or make new playlist?

Tags: c#, .net, axwindowsmediaplayer, asx

I have `.asx` file that contains:

```
<ASX Version="3">
<TITLE>Super FM 104,8 - NICOSIA</TITLE>
<ABSTRACT>Powered by OneStreaming.com</ABSTRACT>
<ENTRY>
<REF HREF = "http://golive.onestreaming.com/super"/>
<REF HREF = "mms://golive.onestreaming.com/super"/>
<REF HREF = "http://live.onestreaming.com/super"/>
<REF HREF = "mms://live.onestreaming.com/super"/>
</ENTRY>
</ASX>
```

I want to make the `axwindowsmediaplayer` play the next link if one is not working.

So my question is... If I put `axwindowsmediaplayer.URL = " .../SuperFM.asx` will it play next link if one is not working or its better to add these links to a playlist to do this?

Note: Please don't start putting downvotes... If you need better explanations just ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it... For those who have same question...

`axwindowsmediaplayer` can play `.asx` files and if `.asx` file have more than one link and lets say the first link is not working, it automatically go to next link, so you don't need to make playlist, it will be the same thing but much more coding...